# Aggregate rows if one row meets a specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to select the sum of the values in the `isOK` column for each `Name` separated, BUT only if `isOK = 1` on `Day = 2`.

The query for the following example table `tablename`

```
Name | Day | isOK  
char | int | int   
-----------------
Flo  |   1 |    1  
Seb  |   1 |    1  
Tim  |   1 |    0  
Flo  |   2 |    1  
Seb  |   2 |    0  
Tim  |   2 |    1
```

should give Flo: 2 and Tim: 1, but not Seb: 1, since his `isOK` on `Day` = 2 is 0.

I've tried using SUM(isOK) with IF constructs, but it's just not working. My alternative solution, to select all `Name` where `isOK` = 1 first and select the SUM(isOK) for each of the names is slow and seems in need of improvement.

I guess it's not that difficult, but I've been trying for hours now and I just can't combine my two queries into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a conditional expression together with a `having` clause like this:

```
select name, sum(isOk) ok_sum
from your_table
group by name
having sum(case when day = 2 and isOK = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

With your sample data the result would be:

```
name    ok_sum
Flo     2
Tim     1
```

As MySQL evaluates boolean expressions as 1 or 0 it should be possible to reduce the condition to this:

```
having sum(day = 2 and isOK = 1) > 0;
```

Another way to do it would be to use a correlated subquery that makes sure there exists a row with `Day = 2` and `isOk = 1` for the `Name`:

```
select t1.name, sum(t1.isOk) ok_sum
from your_table t1
where exists (
    select 1 
    from your_table t2
    where t2.day = 2 and t2.isOK = 1 and t1.name = t2.name
) 
group by t1.name
```

- See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5327/2)

Comment: I added a fiddle that (finally) gave me a response. Maybe it'll give it to others as well, eventually :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant Thanks. I couldn't get the fiddle to work - guess it might time out due to high load or something.

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com/4zTeTC) seems to be more responsive, even if less sexy when it comes to SQL rendering.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Indeed, problem is that it is limited to SQLite, but at least it's fast :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY this :

```
SELECT 
    name, SUM(isok) AS isOk
FROM
    table
GROUP BY `name`
HAVING SUM(`day` = 2 AND isok = 1) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.name, SUM(y.isOK) total
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.name = x.name
 WHERE x.day = 2
   AND x.isok=1
 GROUP
    BY x.name;
```